# Cisco C3750X power supply: difference between /1 vs /2?

Tags: cisco-catalyst

What is the difference between the C3KX-PWR-350WAC/1 and C3KX-PWR-350WAC/2 power supplies for the Catalyst 3750X series? I have a bad power supply, and I can't remove the failed one right now to figure out the model number of the failed one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference. The "/1" resp "/2" are just options when ordering the power supply (1st or 2nd power supply) with a new device.

If you look at the output of `show inventory`, you'll probably only see `C3KX-PWR-350WAC`.

So, when hunting for a replacement, just go after C3KX-PWR-350WAC or C3KX-PWR-350WAC= (the latter formerly being Cisco's part number for a spare unit). Currently, Cisco offer only C3KX-PWR-350WAC-RF (as in "refurbished") on CCW.